# Python: getting NameError: name '-' is not defined error and don't know why

Tags: python, syntax-error

So I'm using this loop to allow someone to choose to be a volunteer if they want to and if they want to, the area in which they want to volunteer. I am getting the error described in the title. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Volunteer = []
PierGate = [0]
GiftShop = [0]
PaintDec = [0]

volunt = str(input("Enter yes if you'd like to be a volunteer or no if you wouldn't: "))
 if volunt == "yes":
  Volunteer.append(volunt)
  print("Ok. Enter 1 to volunteer at pier entrance gate, 2 to volunteer at gift shop or 3 to volunteer at painting and decorating: ")
  VolunteerInput = int(input())
  if VolunteerInput == 1:
      PierGate[0] = PierGate[0]+1
      print("Pier entrance gate it is.")
  elif VounteerInput == 2:
       GiftShop[0] = GiftShop[0]+1
       print("Gift shop it is.")
  elif VolunteerInput == 3:
       PaintDec[0] = PaintDec[0]+1
       print("Painting and decorating it is.")
  else:
      print("Please enter A, B or C.")
 elif volunt == "no":
      print("You have refused to be a volunteer.")
 else: 
      print("Please enter yes or no")
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice two problems here:

1. aligning the codes
2. Variable in line 14 is incorrect. It should be "VolunteerInput" instead of "VounteerInput."

The modified code may be found below. It works for all of the conditions that you specify.

```
Volunteer = []
PierGate = [0]
GiftShop = [0]
PaintDec = [0]

volunt = str(input("Enter yes if you'd like to be a volunteer or no if you wouldn't: "))
if volunt == "yes":
    Volunteer.append(volunt)
    print("Ok. Enter 1 to volunteer at pier entrance gate, 2 to volunteer at gift shop or 3 to volunteer at painting and decorating: ")
    VolunteerInput = int(input())
    if VolunteerInput == 1:
      PierGate[0] = PierGate[0]+1
      print("Pier entrance gate it is.")
    elif VolunteerInput == 2:
       GiftShop[0] = GiftShop[0]+1
       print("Gift shop it is.")
    elif VolunteerInput == 3:
       PaintDec[0] = PaintDec[0]+1
       print("Painting and decorating it is.")
    else:
      print("Please enter A, B or C.")
elif volunt == "no":
  print("You have refused to be a volunteer.")
else: 
  print("Please enter yes or no")
```